# Find all entries in active state without DEADLINE or SCHEDULED

Tags: org-mode

I would like to define a sparse tree search in Org mode which returns all TODO s which are in an active state and do not have either a DEADLINE or SCHEDULE assigned.

I tried `C-c / m` and then entering
`DEADLINE=|SCHEDULED=/!`

but that does not work. `/!` correctly works in returning only action items in an active state but I do not know how to further reduce those which have no DEADLINE or no SCHEDULED date set.

Comment: What is a "TODO in an active state"? What distinguishes them from other TODO items?

Comment: The are on the left side of the `|` as in `#+TODO: TODO(!) | DONE(!) CANCELED(!) DELEGATED(!)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you *almost* got it. Try

```
+DEADLINE=""+SCHEDULED=""/!
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. How would you make it search for active timestamps?