# Search for tasks without any active timestamp

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Running spacemacs 0.200.13 on emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

Just as the title suggests, I want to search for all agenda items without an active timestamp --- either plain active timestamp or a scheduled or deadline timestamp.

How do I do that?

A solution is given [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36309/find-all-entries-in-active-state-without-deadline-or-scheduled) for selecting tasks without a scheduled or deadline timestamp. But that does not work for me. Emacs just goes in some kind of a loop. Agenda is not generated even after 45 secs. Moreover, it does not cover tasks with just a plain active timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the function I use:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("x" agenda)
      ("y" agenda*) ; or agenda entries planned this week/day with an hour specification like [h]h:mm
      ("z" todo "TODO")
      ("n" todo "NEXT")
      ("r" todo "REVISE")
      ("w" todo "WAITING")))

(defun jump-to-org-agenda-all-todos ()
 "open agenda with all unscheduled/non-deadline todos"
 (interactive)
 (org-agenda nil "z"))
```

You can call `org-agenda` (usually `C-c a`) and see a list of the various options, and then substitute in the function above as you like. For details on custom commands see [this entry](https://orgmode.org/manual/Storing-searches.html#Storing-searches).

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure how to use it. I pasted in in my `.spacemacs` and tried running that function. But it produces an error `helm-M-x: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil "open agenda with all unscheduled/non-deadline todos" (interactive) (org-agenda nil "z")), 1` Then I added an option q to `C-c a` and tried useng that option. But it still produced the same error. Could please provide more details?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to include the custom commands! It should work for you now.

Comment: Not sure what the down vote is for, but for more info on custom commands see the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html).